# Report builder connectivity issue from different machine

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, ssas, ssas-tabular

I am trying to connect Report builder from Machine A and my SSRS is deployed in Machine B

Machine A (Client machine with Report Builder 3) --> Machine B (SSRS 2016 - Configured in Native mode)

I am using Windows Authentication and both the machines are not present in domain. I am able to author a report in report builder in Machine B whereas while trying to author a report from Machine A I am getting below error:

> ---
>
> ### Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was >forcibly closed by the remote host.

Any idea on how to solve this will be really helpful.

Comment: Confused. How can you use Windows Authentication if both machines are not present in the domain?

Comment: that is what my problem statement is... During connection it has to use servers windows credential correct?

Comment: Connection to the SQL Database or just to the SSRS portal to deploy the report?

Comment: SSRS portal to deploy the report

Comment: I'm assuming you can't get to the SSRS Report portal from the client either.

Comment: Can you add MachineA\Username to the security on MachineB as an Admin?

Comment: But that will be out of the security Jurisdiction so it is not authenticating

Comment: Trying to use pass through authentication.

Comment: Got a breakthru where I am trying to open the Report Builder as a separate application not from IE, and author the reports and while publishing use servers userid and credential

Comment: Ah. I never open RB from IE.